# What is the missing number in this wheel?

Tags: logical-deduction, visual

[image]
What's the missing number? From [World of Engineering](https://twitter.com/engineers_feed/status/1582979260251140096).

Comment: I'm not sure if I've followed the rules correctly, please let me know so I can edit the post.

Comment: This type of questions is not the best (similar to number sequences) if you do not know the simply explained solution. If you know the solution, some other tag would be desired (e.g. lateral-thinking or number sequence ...)

Comment: I don't know the solution, should I change the tags? Or maybe simply delete the post if it's not appropriate for Puzzling.

Comment: There's no puzzle posted. You could post a link to any kind of published puzzle, but it is not a question.

Comment: Would it make sense to reformulate the post in some way? I'm really curious about how this problem is solved and I'm not sure how to ask for help. Should it be posted in a different forum perhaps?

Comment: Leave it here as it is ... maybe someone will found a  solution based on some transformation of numbers (letters, words, latin etc.) better than those on original link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, may be useful to share that I found here [World of Engineering](https://twitter.com/engineers_feed/status/1530783116956094464) **the same puzzle with different numbers position**!!

[image]

**Most of those** "*number in wheel*" problem patterns are about the **opposite/diagonal** side, looking at the two examples below:

[image]

That will be solved like this:

> 11:1x1=1 , 24:2x4=8 , 36:3x6=18,  Then 13:1x3= **3**

**The second one is**:

[image]

That will be solved like this:

> ALL Diagonal sum up to 24.  14+10 = 13+11 = 18+6, then 4+**20** =`24`

### In our case

**I solved like this**:

> [image]

> So, the missing number is **7**

.

Comment: Beautiful answer! How about the other way around? 10^2 = 100, but 1 + 0 + 0 does not equal 8. Does it make sense to seek this kind of symmetry in these kinds of problems?

Comment: @Tsiolkovsky, Thanks for this note. It's really wired!! I think there is another logic for the 2nd one, maybe for example ( summing prim factor, or sum of divisors!) (1: have one divisor=1); (10: have 1,2,5 the sum will be 8); (9: have 3 two times, maybe 6); then 5 is a prime number, may the result is **1**

Answer (score 0):

> [image]

> the missing number is 2 because it looks like a double mirrored 5, and is the  difference between 8 and 10. this is all wrong yet whatever.